# CouchDB best practices - all entities in a single db vs a new db for each entity?

Tags: couchdb

I am starting with CouchDB. What is the accepted best practice to utilize databases? A single database per application storing all kinds of entities with smth like "_type" property to discriminate one from another or a separate database for each kind of entity?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One database with lots of different types of document, so you can take advantage of [View Collation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation). Note that top-level names prefixed with an underscore, e.g. *_type*, are reserved for CouchDB.